# Drawing several countries ingnoring borders

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, cran

I used the tips in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126745/gadm-maps-cross-country-comparision-graphics) to draw the maps of several countries. Now I need to ignore the borders between some countries. . Any Suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `rgeos` package to merge some of the polygons. Take a look at the `unionSpatialPolygons` function from the `maptools` package. This can use `rgeos` as a backend. See also [this post](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/maptools-and-rgeos-td5013007.html) on r-sig-geo.