# Map of India in R with Different Values of Five Indicators for Every State of India

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gis, rgooglemaps

I want to generate a map of India in R. I have five indicators with different values of every state. I want to plot bubbles with five different colors, and their size should represent their intensity in every state. For example:

`State    A    B   C   D   E

Kerala  - 39,   5,  34, 29, 11

Bihar - 6,  54, 13, 63, 81

Assam - 55, 498,    89, 15, 48,

Chandigarh - 66,    11, 44, 33, 71`

I have gone through some links related to my problem:

[1] http://www.r-bloggers.com/nrega-and-indian-maps-in-r/

[2] [An R package for India?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997276/an-r-package-for-india)

But these links could not serve my purpose. Any help in this direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried

```
library(mapproj)
map(database= "world", regions  = "India", exact=T, col="grey80", fill=TRUE, projection="gilbert", orientation= c(90,0,90))

lat <- c(23.30, 28.38)

lon <- c(80, 77.12) # Lon and Lat for two cities Bhopal and Delhi

coord <- mapproject(lon, lat, proj="gilbert", orientation=c(90, 0, 90))

points(coord, pch=20, cex=1.2, col="red")
```

In nut shell problems are:
(1) It does not give me plot at district level. Not even boundries of states.
(2) How to create bubbles or dots of my data in this plot, if I have only name of locations and corresponding value to plot?
(3) can this be done in easily in `library(RgoogleMaps)` or `library(ggplot2)`? (Just a guess, I do not know much about these packages)

Comment: Do you really need to add five bubbles in each state? That seems to take up quite a bit of space; you may not have enough space to add five bubbles for some small states. I wonder if you may want to have five separated India maps.

Comment: Can you provide the code by which you created the map of India?

Comment: Dear lawyeR & jazzurro, I followed the codes from above links, as i do not have any knowledge about geographical maps in R. But I could not find these codes working for me.  You are right in saying that map would have less space, specially for smaller states. I will try to manage with three indicators.

Comment: The answers you linked were outdaed because the GADM links have changed. I have edited them (the edits should be live soon), and this should work to get you started on plotting the map of India: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=zJd1RfjS

Comment: @Molx: thank you for all your work and the code on r-fiddle.  The final line returned an error: > IND <- getCountries("IND",level=1)
 
 Error in changeGADMPrefix(theFile, fileName) : 
  could not find function "spChFIDs"

Comment: I also downloaded the shape file for India from the link http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata It is a zip file. I extracted it in my working directory. Then I executed the following lines  `library(maptools)` `India <- readShapeSpatial('IND_adm1.shp')`  `plot(India)` . It gives me a plot for India, but aftermath i do not know.

Comment: @lawyeR I forgot to save the addition of `library(sp)` to the beggining of the R-Fiddle code. That's where `spChFIDs` is.

Comment: Also posted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144003.

Answer (score 3):

As @lawyeR states, a choropleth (or thematic) map is more commonly used to represent variables on a map. This would require you to produce one map per variable. Let me take you through an example:

```
require("rgdal")  # needed to load shapefiles

# obtain India administrative shapefiles and unzip
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/IND_adm.zip", 
              destfile = "IND_adm.zip")
unzip("IND_adm.zip", overwrite = TRUE)

# load shapefiles
india <- readOGR(dsn = "shapes/", "IND_adm1")

# check they've loaded correctly with a plot
plot(india)

# all fine. Let's plot an example variable using ggplot2
require("ggplot2")
require("rgeos")  # for fortify() with SpatialPolygonsDataFrame types

india@data$test <- sample(65000:200000000, size = nrow(india@data),
                          replace = TRUE)

# breaks the shapefile down to points for compatibility with ggplot2
indiaF <- fortify(india, region = "ID_1")
indiaF <- merge(indiaF, india, by.x = "id", by.y = "ID_1")

# plots the polygon and fills them with the value of 'test'
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = indiaF, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
                                  fill = test)) +
  coord_equal()
```

Finally, I notice you asked the same question on GIS SE. This is considered bad practice and is generally frowned upon, so I've flagged that question to be closed as a duplicate of this. As a general rule of thumb try not to create duplicates.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh sorry! I did not know this. I will take care of this in future. Thanks Phil.

Comment: That's fine, it takes a while to get the hang of things, so I hope to be helpful rather than judgemental :)

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Note that if you are having problems with readOGR, `india <- readOGR(dsn = "shapes/", "IND_adm1")` needs `IND_adm1.shp` file in directory `shapes`.  Default unzip location for me wasn't `shapes/`, I manually put extracted files in `shapes` folder. I also had to change `dsn = "shapes/"` to `dsn = "shapes"`.

Comment: If you only want states data (most useful case ig), you can remove lines starting with `india@..` (which is for testing only anyways) and `indiaF <- merge(..`. Check `indiaF` now, you will have column called `id`, which are id numbers of the states. You can check `IND_adm1.csv` to see which id belongs to which state. If you've removed `test`, just change `fill = test` with `fill = id` to see each states colored differently.  Now you can color them according to your numerical variable by changing `fill = <your vairable>`. Using `RColorBrewer` will be best option for choropleth maps.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the shapefile for India, you need to create a **choropleth**.  That will take the shapefule map and color each State in India on a gradient that reflects your data.  You may want to create a panel of five plots, each one showing India and its states colored according to one of your five variables.

For others who can push this answer farthr, here is the `dput` of the data frame, after a bit of cleaning.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(State = c("Kerala", "Bihar", "Assam", "Chandigarh"
), A = c("39", "6", "55", "66"), B = c("5", "54", "498", "11"
), C = c("34", "13", "89", "44"), D = c("29", "63", "15", "33"
), E = c("11", "81", "48", "71")), .Names = c("State", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E"), row.names = c("Kerala", "Bihar", "Assam", "Chandigarh"
), class = "data.frame")
```